# android view-like transition using a single view

Tags: android, animation, view, transition

I am trying to spice up an existing app by making use of transitions. In many places I have single views that change their contents and I was wondering if it is possible to animate the changing of the content.

For example, what I am looking for is when the contents of a listview change (say via a notifydatasetinvalidated) to animate that in some way (existing contents slide out right and new contents slide in left).

I am aware I can do that with two alternating views but it is a bit of work to do that across the app.